# Connectedness of hyperplane sections (reference request)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Dear colleagues,

Could you give me a reference (not a proof:) to the following folklore result. If $X\subset\mathbb P^n$ is a smooth irreducible projective variety of dimension $>1$, then *any* hyperplane section of $X$ is connected. The base field is algebraically closed, characteristic is arbitrary.

Thank you in advance,
Serge

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fulton%E2%80%93Hansen_connectedness_theorem

Comment: @Vivek. Wow, I had now idea that even *this* is on Wiki:) Thanks, I will look up the paper.

Comment: The Fulton-Hansen theory is more general, but this particular case is the Lemma of Enriques-Severi-Zariski, which is older.

Comment: @jason. Thanks! Could you give an explicit reference?

Comment: ( Hartshorne, Algebraic Geometry, Springer, GTM 52, Cor. 7.9, p. 244 )

Comment: @Damian. Oops! Shame on me. Thank you^)