# Class of varieties closed under finite products/hyperplane sections and containing curves and projective spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Let $C$ be a collection of positive-dimensional connected smooth projective $k$-schemes. Is it possible that

- a $k$-scheme isomorphic to a member of $C$ (an an abstract scheme) is in $C$;
- $C$ contains all one-dimensional connected smooth projective $k$-schemes and all projective spaces over $k$;
- the fiber product $\cdot\times_{\mathrm{Spec}\,k}\cdot$ of any two members of $C$ is in $C$;
- any smooth hyperplane section of the image of any projective embedding of a member of $C$ of dimension$\geq 2$ is in $C$.
- there is a positive-dimensional connected smooth projective $k$-scheme that is not in $C$?

Comment: I'm not sure that I'understanding the question. You can just take as $C$ all the projective k-schemes minus a surface which is neither $\mathbb{P}^2$ nor a product of curves...

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi how to see that your class is closed under taking products and hyperplane sections?

Comment: Oh, right. It is not closed under hyperplane sections

Comment: @DanielMcLaury well, it is (under the restriction on dimension): https://mathoverflow.net/q/131063/137767

Comment: It is easy to find such schemes using (etale) fundamental groups. If you start with all smooth projective curves and projective spaces, then the Lefschetz hyperplane section theorem tells you that the fundamental groups of all varieties you construct will precisely be all groups that are finite products of fundamental groups of smooth projective curves and there are many smooth projective varieties with fundamental groups not in this class.

Comment: Another (similar) option: take for $C$ the class of smooth projective varieties $X$ such that the abelian variety $\,\underline{\operatorname{Pic}}^{\mathrm{o}}(X)\, $ is isomorphic to a product of Jacobians of curves. This has the required properties: the only nontrivial one is the stability for hypersurface sections, which follows from the Lefschetz theorem. But a general abelian variety of dimension $\geq 4$ does not belong to $C$.